# Summing up value for hidden field when checkbox is clicked not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sum

I have a checkbox but has the value assigned to the item's name. Now i have this hidden field which has the value assigned to the item's price. now when i run my jquery using the hidden field to calculate the sum of the selected items, it doesn't work. It works the other way around when i assign the price and calc ID to the checkbox and not the hidden field.

Here's my jquery:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function calcscore(){
      var score = 0;
        $(".calc:checked").each(function(){
         score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
              });
            $('#price').text(score.toFixed(2));
 $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
   }
  $().ready(function(){
  $(".calc").change(function(){
     calcscore()
 });
});
  </script>
```

And my html:

```
        <li>
        <label>
         <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]"  value="Title1"/>
         The Title
         </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="title8" value="250">
       </li>


             <li>
               <label>
              <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]"  value="Title1"/>The Title
         </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="title8" value="150">
       </li>

      <p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span></p>
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: and you wish to calculate the sum of the hidden values which corresponds to the checkboxes respectively ?

Comment: check if the answer suites you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be more like the solution below and check how it would be working on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yehiaawad/wwtwmaLv/
Your HTML:

```
    <li>
    <label>
     <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]"  value="Title1"/>
     The Title
      <input type="hidden" name="title8" value="250">

     </label>
   </li>
         <li>
           <label>
          <input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]"  value="Title1"/>The Title
                  <input type="hidden" name="title8" value="150">
     </label>
   </li>
      <p>Total: PHP <span id="price">0</span></p>
```

Your JS

```
     function calcscore(){
      var score = 0;
        var checked=$(".calc:checked ~   input[type=hidden]").each(function(){
        score+=parseInt($(this).val());
        });
 $('#price').text(score.toFixed(2));
   }
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".calc").change(function(){
     calcscore()
 });
});
```

Comment: hey that worked @yehia, thanks! now to add another curve ball to the problem is, i also hooked the class="calc" into a radio button. now that it's working with the checkboxes, it's not working on the radio button.

Here the structure of the radio button for reference:

                        <li>
     <label>
             <input class="calc" type="radio" name="herbs" value="Title3"/>
            Title3
             </label>
          <input type="hidden" name="title7" value="<123">
       </li>

Comment: Solved it by putting the title in the radio button and the price in the hidden field value. also made the $_POST much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you reached it,would be nice to accept the answer if it helped you )

Comment: Under the Vote Down button there is a tick )